# Nesting Multiple Quotations Inline JS

Tags: javascript, html

I'm looking to add a bit of inline JS to a certain selection of jQuery (I realize that this is bad practice, but it's fine for a simple userscript, I believe). My code essentially gets me this type of jQuery object:

```
[<a *tags*>​text</a>​]
```

to which I then use

```
*each element of selection*.after('<a href="javascript:definedFunction(\"Argument\");">text2</a>');
```

where `definedFunction(param)` is a function that takes a single `string` as an argument and has already been defined in a previous script and is available for my use (I believe?).

My problem is that when I run this code, I get `text2` pointing to `javascript:definedFunction(`. I know I'm not using the escape sequences right, so if someone could please explain to me the proper way of doing that I would appreciate it.

What I'm *trying* to achieve is the injection of this:

```
<a href = "javascript:definedFunction("Argument");">text2</a>
```

which I know is also missing some escape characters, though again I'm not sure where.

EDIT:

What if I was to replace `Argument` with a function that returns a string, and/or the name of a string variable?

Comment: Look at your HTML. Does it look valid to you?

Comment: I realize that the HTML I have posted at the bottom is invalid. I believe the quotes around `Argument` might need to be changed to &quot? I'm not really sure, I just know that what's above is wrong.

Comment: Well, why don't you try `&quot;`?

Answer (score 0):

If you do use strings around strings, it can appear ambiguous to javascript. That being said, sometimes it makes sense to do it, and you just need to use different quotes " or ' to ensure it is properly evaluated. TLDR - alternate your strings " and '
you can also escape your quotation marks using "\""